# .htaccess on subdomain wordpress permalink config

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain

I am struggling with wordpress permalink setup. My blog is on a domain:

http://www.siteX.com/site/blog/

With an IP config the blog can be reach from a different URL:

http://blog.siteY.com/.

If activating the permalink option in wordpress the site get a "forbidden" on opening it in the browser.

Followin code can be found in the htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any hints on how the code has to be modified to get it running?

Many thanks,

Comment: On WordPress you can only have 1 main domain. Which of the two would you like to be the main domain? And what is filled in the general settings?

Comment: This should be the main domain entered in the WP konfig:http://blog.siteY.com/.